# Qt application: how to add license requirement

Tags: qt, license-key

I have implemented my Qt Application, and I want to distribute it. Now, I want to add license requirement for my application, but I don't know a appropriat method.

The more details about my license requirement is:

For anyone with license key, he can use my application 10 times for free. For 11 time, a license code is required, or the application can not be opened.
About how to count how many times the application is opened, I want to record it in regedit. Every time the application is opened, the regedit is read and decide whether the application has been opened for 10 times.

But, my question is: if user remove the record from regedit, the application would treat the computer as a new one, and record the open time as 0 time.

My question is: is there any method to record some information that the user can not remove/change? I want to know how other client software add the license requirement?